# Inviting group members to a Facebook event

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I would like to create an event under a group, review it and some time later send invites to the group members. I recall having done this in the past but cannot see the option now.

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating the event, there is an option that says "Invite members of the host group to this event", but I'm not sure that it is possible to do so after the event has been created -- the option is no longer there when you go to edit the event or invite friends. I think you will have to invite the group members right from the start when creating the event, or else select them manually afterward.